# US citizen traveling to New Zealand via Australia

Tags: visas, transit, australia, us-citizens, new-zealand

Do I need any types of visas to travel from USA to New Zealand via Australia?  I am a US citizen.

Comment: It depends on your citizenship, are you a US citizen?

Comment: @Relaxed: The title seems to imply so :-)  I edited it into the body as well.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed. It's the second time today I miss a detail that's in the title of the question :-(

Comment: Yankee go ... er ... I mean, welcome :-). I assume somebody here knows but if not and web is mute (unlikely) advise and I can check locally. I'd assume NZ immigration website is very clear on this.

Comment: [No, you do not](http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia).

Comment: It probably depends on the purpose of your travel.  If you are traveling for an uncommon purpose, please advise.

Answer (score 5):

Australia has a kind of quasi-visa very much like the US own ESTA, called [Electronic Travel Authority](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETAS3/etas). US citizens have to apply online in advance and pay a fee if they want to enter the country, even for a short visit.

But if you are only transiting through an Australian airport, don't need to leave the transit lounge and will leave within 8 hours of landing, [you do not need a visa](http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia).

US citizens (and nationals) do not need a visa for [a visit of up to 90 days in New Zealand](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/visit).